# Attach DLL to ASP.NET Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll, iis-7

How do you attach a DLL to a asp.net site? I want to be able to debug and edit the DLL without having to keep replacing the reference in my asp.net site. I checked attach to process but didn't see the worker process. I am using asp.net, IIS 7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just put it into /bin folder of your web application.

#### OR

Add reference to this .dll by right clicking on `References > Add Reference > Browse >` Select your .dll file and lick OK.

Then set it's "Copy Local" property to "True". This way .dll will be copied into /Bin folder each time you build application.

[alt text http://xmages.net/out.php/i170817_1.png](http://xmages.net/out.php/i170817_1.png)

Comment: You can replace it at any time later.

Comment: ..with a new or modified version.

Comment: for clarification, you would need to decompile a dll to "edit" it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197397/how-do-i-decompile-a-dll-file

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio you should create a solution that has your website as a project and the DLL (code) as another project. Make a reference in the website project to the DLL project and it should update it automatically.

If you are not using the web application model and just the website model you could just have your DLL project output to your website's /bin directory directly. That will update the DLL in the website/bin folder whenever you build your DLL project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the dll, open that project up in a second instance of Visual Studio and treat it like you would for any other project.

Set the reference in your /bin folder to the debug dll that the second Visual Studio creates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have Visual Studio...

If you're just trying to add a dll, you can add a reference to it by right clicking on your website node and choosing "Add Reference..." .
You will be able to debug the dll if you have its pdb along with it (to load the symbols from). You will NOT be able to edit the dll.

If the dll is in fact another project you have the source code for, just add the project to your solution, and from your website project add a reference from the "projects" tab. VS should add a reference and dependency so that it keeps the dll updated when you change code in your dll project.